# calculate date from utc time and percentage

Tags: php, utc, date-conversion

I am trying to work out current percentage complete between given dates using start date and todays date. The duration between the two is calcuklated via end date. These values to be used in javascript. `startdate = 2013-01-08` and `end date = 2013-07-08` and todays realtime date. to test I am trying to convert my result and see it is returning the correct date. the code is as follows:

```
$duration = ( ((strtotime($model['ProjectEndDate']) - 1*86400)*1000) - ((strtotime($model['StartDATE']) - 1*86400)*1000) );
            echo $duration;
            echo "<br>";

            $burn = ((time() - 1*86400)*1000) - ((strtotime($model['StartDATE']) - 1*86400)*1000);
            echo $burn;
            echo "<br>";

            $pBurned = $burn/$duration;
            echo $pBurned*100;
            echo "<br>";

            $time = $time = strtotime( ($date_from + $pBurned) );
            echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
```

The output is

```
1.56348E+10
14212291000
90.901648885819
1970-01-01 01:00:00
```

**Update to:**

```
$today = time();
            $startdate = strtotime($model['StartDATE']); //
            $enddate = strtotime($model['ProjectEndDate']); // 


            $diff_total = $enddate - $startdate;
            echo $diff_total;
            echo "<br>";

            $diff_today = $today - $startdate;
            echo $diff_today;
            echo "<br>";

            $percentage_date=round(($diff_today/$diff_total)*100,2);
            //echo $diff_today/$diff_total;
            echo $percentage_date.'%';
            exit();
```

gives the output

```
15634800
14219916
90.95%
```

What I want to do with this now is calculate 90.95% from startdate and return date.

Comment: in javascript month starts from 0 so I am minusing 1 month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

search for maths on working out percentages. no joke i did.

```
$today = new DateTime();
$startdate = new DateTime("2013-06-16"); //$model['StartDATE']
$enddate = new DateTime("2013-06-26"); // $model['ProjectEndDate']

$diff_total = $enddate->diff($startdate)->format("%a");    
$diff_today = $today->diff($startdate)->format("%a");    
$percentage_date=round(($diff_today/$diff_total)*100,2);

echo $percentage_date.'%'; // from today
```

get percentage of a date

```
$percentage_to_get = 45;
$percentage_of_days =  floor(($diff_total/100*)$percentage_to_get);
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime( $startdate->format('Y-m-d') ." + $percentage_of_days day") );
```

Comment: what you want to do now makes nosense as 90% of the date would print today right?

Comment: say percent was 45, with the given dates above in question how would I calculate 45 percent from startdate?

Comment: with the dates `2013-01-08`, `2013-07-08` and 70.00% the date returned is `2013-05-14`, is this correct?